# What are the differences in the meaning of "static" in C++ and Objective C?

Tags: c++, objective-c, static

Objective-C and C++ belong to the C family, so in terms of "static", there are static variables, static functions, static classes etc.

Static has static storage, lifecycle, scope.

Here is the question:

- What are the big differences in the meaning of "static" in C++ and Objective C?

Comment: Object C? Do you mean Objective-C?

Comment: static has enough different meaning in C++ alone you don't need to bring objective-C into it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`static` has the exact same meaning in Objective-C that it would have in C. It does *not* mean the same thing as in C++. In C++, `static` is additionally used to declare and define class methods (methods which can only be called on the class itself) and variables, but Objective-C distinguishes class and instance methods with different syntax:

```
+ (void)classMethod;
- (void)instanceMethod;
```

and does not support class variables.

Answer (score 1):

`static` in Objective-C is identical to its plain C counterpart (specifying the variable linkage). While C++ supports this usage of `static`, it extends the meaning of the `static` keyword to declaring class methods as well.